# how to drag gridview row from one grid to another

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, drag-and-drop

I have a gridview with rows.  I'd like the user to be able to grab a row, and move it to one of several other gridviews on the winform.  How can I go about doing this?  I'm not familiar with how to implement drag and drop here.

Any good tutorials on this sort of drag and drop?  Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Ok, I have the following code (to drag from gridPODetails to dataGridView1.  Its not working yet, but I"m closer (now I get drag arrow and plus sign in the destination).  What am I missing?

```
 private void gridPODetails_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = gridPODetails.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (info.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //DataRowView view = (DataRowView)gridPODetails.Rows[info.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;  //WRONG
        DataRow view = ((DataTable)(gridPODetails.DataSource)).Rows[info.RowIndex];  //RIGHT
        if (view != null)
        {
            gridPODetails.DoDragDrop(view, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView grid = sender as DataGridView;
    DataTable table = grid.DataSource as DataTable;
    DataRow row = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataRow)) as DataRow;

    if (row != null && table != null && row.Table != table)
    {
        table.ImportRow(row);
        row.Delete();
    }
}
```

SOLVED: See my edit above.  I was actually grabbing the entire datatable, not just the row I wanted.  Of course the destination only knows how to work with Rows, not entire tables.  Now its working!

Comment: @Charles -Yes, I'm not sure what else that could mean?

Comment: Deleted my answer.  The grid in question is a DevExpress grid.  It's notthe standard DataGridView.  I am so sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @David Stratton -I've actually found some of it useful (although incomplete).  The real gridview has a HitTest feature for doing the same thing.

Comment: @David Stratton -Between your link and this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/DataGridView_Drag-n-Drop.aspx I'm closer.  Still missing something though.

Comment: @David Stratton -Put your link back as an answer, it helped me and you deserve the answer.

Comment: @MAW74656 - OK.  Thanks, but I think you really answered it on your own - I just pointed you in a wrong direction that was, fortunately, at least CLOSE to the right direction.   You CAN answer your own questions and accept that if you like, and it might be more helpful to the next user to stumble across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on a [Bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=drag%20and%20drop%20gridview%20winforms&qs=n&sk=&first=11&FORM=PORE).  It looks like exactly what you're looking for.

http://tv.devexpress.com/Content/XtraGrid/XtraGridDragRowsBetweenGrids/XtraGridDragRowsBetweenGrids.pdf

Comment: -This looks perfect, I'm going to try to use and let you know how it went.  You don't think the video is available online?

Comment: I don't think so, but I found the printed article easy to follow.  I have to thank you for asking.  It's been a LONG while since I tried to figure out how to do this, and I gave it up as not worth the effort.  (I was a relatively new developer back then.) Now I find this article and it looks a LOT easier than it did when I was learning .NET 1.0.

Comment: -Is this code referring to the built-in .NET gridview, or a custom control from devexpress?

Comment: -I'm not able to declare a GridHitInfo object.  Is there some strange namespace I have to add?

Comment: Darn it.  It's a DevExpress Grid - my answer is worthless to you.  The video is available, but that's a moot point now.  Sorry.

Comment: -This answer is not correct by itself, but using the code provided here helped me figure out how to do the same with stock .NET DataGridView.  See edits to question for working final code.